# SaveFileDialog not showing existing files

Tags: winforms, savefiledialog

I've got a `SaveFileDialog` that doesn't show the existing *pdf* files when I have ".pdf File" seleted. Why is that? Any existing png files show up just fine when I've got ".png Image" selected in the dialog, so I'm not sure why only the existing pdf files aren't showing up.

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.AddExtension = true;
sfd.Filter = ".pdf File | *.pdf |.png Image | *.png";
sfd.CheckPathExists = true;
sfd.OverwritePrompt = true;
sfd.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = false;
sfd.ValidateNames = true;
sfd.ShowDialog();
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, but I couldn't find it asked anywhere despite thinking that this would be a common problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the spaces in the extension passed to the Filter property

```
sfd.Filter = ".pdf File|*.pdf|.png Image|*.png";
```

Comment: That was exactly it, thank you! I haven't really used the filter before.